# How can I merge several files on SPSS by variable label?

Tags: spss

I have 48 .sav data sets containing results of a monthly survey. I need to merge the cases of all common variables from them, in order to come up with a 4 years aggregate. As I'm new to SPSS and I'm not very proficient with syntax (although i can follow it) I would normally do this using Data - Merge files - Add Cases but most of these common variables have different variable names on each data set as the questions are not always formulated in the same order and some questions only appear on one or two data sets.

However, the variable labels do not change from one data set to another. It would be great if someone knows a way to merge this data sets by variable label instead of variable name. Swapping variable names and variable labels would also do as then I could use Data - Merge files - Add Cases without problems.

Many thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge procedures such as ADD FILES (Data > Merge Files > Add Cases) provide a capability to rename variables in the input files before merging.  However, if there are a lot of variables to merge, this would get pretty tedious and error prone.  Also, the dialog box supports only merging two files, while syntax allows up to 50.

Variable labels are generally not valid as variable names due to the typical presence of characters such as blanks and punctuation and length restrictions.  If you have a rule that could be used to turn labels into valid variable names, that could be automated, or if the variables are always in the same order and are present in all the files, they could be renamed something like V1, V2, ...

The renaming could be done manually in syntax that you would craft for each file, or this could be done with a short Python program that you run on each file.  I can write that for you if you provide details and, preferably, a sample dataset to test with (jkpeck AT gmail.com).

The Python code could loop over all the sav files in a directory and apply the renaming logic to each in one step.